# Postfix: Order of evaluation of `smtpd_client_restrictions`, `smtpd_helo_restrictions`, `smtpd_relay_restrictions` and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`

Tags: postfix, e-mailrelay

In what order does Postfix > 2.10 evaluate the following directives?

1. `smtpd_client_restrictions`
2. `smtpd_helo_restrictions`
3. `smtpd_relay_restrictions`
4. `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`

I read [Postfix SMTP relay and access control (ACCESS README)](https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) and [Postfix Configuration Parameters](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) as well as the comments in `main.cf`, but IMHO the advices are not absolutely clear or even contradictory.

Note: When I speak about a "local address" I refer to any recipient address which Postfix is somehow the final destination, i.e. an address whose domain part is listed in `mydestination`, `virtual_alias_domains` or `virtual_mailbox_domains`. Everything else is a non-local address and Postfix must forward the mail to another MTA.

*Question 1:* Are the first two directives always evaluated for any type of client (MUA and other SMTP servers) and any destination address in the specified order? I assume so.

*Question 2:* Is `smtpd_relay_restrictions` a) always evaluated or b) only evaluated for non-local mail domains?

*Question 3:* Is `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` a) always evaluated or b) only evaluated for local addresses?

*Some quotes from the documentation*

The documentation for [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) states *optional restrictions that the Postfix SMTP server applies in the context of a client RCPT TO command, after smtpd_relay_restrictions.* This suggests that `smtpd_relay_restrictions` is always evaluated, incl. local addresses. But the name of the directive rather implies that it is only considered for non-local addresses which are forwarded/relayed.

The documentation for [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) states *as of Postfix 2.10, relay permission rules are preferably implemented with `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, so that a permissive spam blocking policy under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` will no longer result in a permissive mail relay policy.* This suggests, that `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is only considered for local addresses, but skipped for non-local addresses.

However, there is a comment for `smtpd_relay_resrictions` in the default `main.cf` which states *no default action (permit or reject) is put at the end, because for external mail servers, this list is combined with `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and hence an early `reject` would abort prematurely.* This suggests that `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is always evaluated.

Comment: You seem to be wondering about some of the design decisions in the context of one particular postfix version. Some of which however are merely necessitated by the goal of ensuring older configuration does not easily produce unexpected or dangerous behaviour. **You probably want to just do what is recommended for your *still maintained* version of Postfix (at the moment, that is `3.5.19` or later) and avoid deprecated features and compatibility special cases entirely.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those names mostly correspond to SMTP session stages. The main document to refer to is [SMTPD ACCESS README](https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html).

First is client connecting, so `smtpd_client_restrictions` are evaluated. On this stage what is available is remote IP address, its DNS reverse and forward of the reverse.

Then it issues HELO or EHLO, so `smtpd_helo_restrictions` are evaluated next. The name presented is additionally available on this stage.

Next is `MAIL FROM`, so `smtpd_sender_restrictions` is next with additional information — envelope sender.

Next is `RCPT TO` which makes envelope recipient available. But here's the trick: the server now makes the decision on how it will relay the mail; so `smtpd_relay_restrictions` is evaluated here. `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is evaluated next. This is explained in [`man 5 postconf`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions).

Next are `smtpd_data_restrictions` and `smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions`, which are rarely used.

**All** of these restrictions are **always evaluated** in this order **for each mail** until decision is made. This does not depend on this server being the final destination or not. It stops evaluation when definite decision (permit, reject, defer) is made, so for example if client was rejected at HELO stage (by something in `smtpd_helo_restrictions`), `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` will not be evaluated. However, if `smtpd_delay_reject = yes`,  the connection will still progress to RCPT TO stage, but since decision is already made, no restriction lists are evaluated; Postfix simply fast skips everything and postpones the joy of rejecting the client after it also provides the envelope sender and recipient, so it also logs that information.

Additionally, **milters** are called for each stage. Milters are [called *after*](https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#when-inspect) the corresponding restrictions list.

For completeness: ETRN control path is entirely different. First of all, `smtpd_client_restrictions` and `smtpd_helo_restrictions` are evaluated, and if `ETRN` command is used (instead of `MAIL FROM` which is normally used here), connection is diverted to that path, where it only checks `smtpd_etrn_restrictions`.

Comment: >> All of these restrictions are always evaluated in this order **for each mail** until decision is made.
>>

If all directives are evaluated, why do we need more than one? Why not simply put everything into `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` when all information is available?

I know there is a section [Dangerous use of `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#danger), but I don't get the idea. The "dangerous" use is due to a wrong order of rule which unintentionally accepts too early. But this kind of misconfiguration is also possible if split.

Comment: @user2690527 If you want to explore the alternative of stacking restriction classes, lookup how *linux PAM* does it. Which holds one of the top spots of configuration languages that mere mortals should just leave at the defaults because of how unlikely it is that they will get their modification right.

Comment: Wietse Venema thinks this way it's harder to misconfigure Postfix that way. Yet possible, you're right, but for that you need to alter both knobs; the default value of `smtpd_relay_restrictions` makes sure that there is at least some protection even if you totally bust `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. Many how-tos simply don't mention the former, so this really makes it safer for those who don't read official manuals. There is no other reason. Both lists are really evaluated one after another.

Comment: Understood. I can even accept that splitting the checks into several "stages" may help to gently push administrators towards writing more secure configurations. However, IMHO there should be an explicit sentence in the documentation which clearly states that all these stages are always evaluated and that splitting them is more of a cosmetic decision. Also the names are quite misleading `relay_restrictions` is not specific to relaying mails but evaluates RCPT TO. That's fine with me, but this should be clearly stated in the docs.

Comment: This is stated in the documentation, I provided the direct link...

Comment: No it is not. I read the documentation several times. I also had the link to that documentation in my original question. There is not a clear and explicit statement that every directive is always evaluated for each mail in the same order. You may prove me wrong by a quotation. The documentation only explains its intended purpose for each directive. And that is what make the documentation so dangerously confusing. When someone writes, that `smtpd_relay_restrictions` is used to restrict mail relay, one could easily assume that the directive is also only evaluated for mail relay.

Comment: Aha, that means you don't quite understand the idea behind Postfix mail routing engine. `smtpd` has no distinction between "inbound" or "outbound" or "relayed" mail; these terms we invent for ourselves on top of the more generic framework. `smtpd` process just gets all its mail into "incoming" queue and it is not the one who controls where it will be routed further (to SMTP for external delivery or to LMTP or whatever for local delivery). Consider reading [Postfix Architecture Overview](https://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov, thank you for the explaining and I can imagine each stages now! However I'm confused by how people configure their `reject_rhsbl_sender`, `reject_rhsbl_helo` in the non-related restrictions. Example both `reject_rhsbl_sender` and `reject_rhsbl_helo` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` but omitted `reject_rhsbl_recipient`. I mean since each restrictions are evaluated why not just let `reject_rhsbl_helo` sit in `smtpd_helo_restrictions` and get rejected before other going through other stages? Is there any intentional of doing this or it actually offers advantages?!

Comment: For a long time (I don't remember which version, very long ago) Postfix allows you to use checks that belong to earlier stages of mail processing. E.g. in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` you are allowed to use *anything* that would go into client, helo and sender restrictions. This allows you to keep all your checking in a single list, which is considered an advantage by some people, and also this has one clear disadvantage of accedentally allowing mail which you weren't meant to allow (see links in the answer). I personally prefer to assign checks to where it belongs.

Comment: Also, `reject_rhsbl_helo`, `reject_rhsbl_sender` and `reject_rhsbl_recipient` have different functions. First one checks the data received in HELO/EHLO, second one in MAIL FROM, last one in RCPT TO — all of them are different data. One doesn't necessitate the use of another, it all depends on your needs and requirements.

Comment: Hey Nikita, appreciated! Sadly, I'm not be able to understand each of them and by implementing these all definitely have it's own drawback. However, a legit mail server should have lesser(still possible) problems. Just in case my client complaint about they can't receive email from someone, I'll just manually whitelist them in the relevent restrictions or probably request their IT to correct the configurtion with the minimal RFC-compliant configurations in order to reduce the false report. 

Comment: Usually you add DNS BLs at the very end of the restrictions, and add check_client_access and check_sender_access somewhere before checks to whitelist them. In the files that are referenced by these whitelist checks, you fill either (failed) sender IP addresses, email domain names or whole email addresses you wanting to whitelist. Notice that even in the recipient restrictions you use *sender* checks, because you want to whitelist by sender email addresses. Search more carefully on SF, I definitely answered the complete restrictions setting built with these in mind.